# Output within a range dependent on the iteration and the limit

Tags: javascript

I need a function that outputs a value within a range depending on where the iteration is compared to the limit.

```
var limit = 90;   //Can change
var range = 3;    //1,2,3 - Can change
var iteration = 0;

function {
   var output = //number between 0 and range-1
                //dependent on iteration/limit;

   console.log(output);
   iteration++;
}
```

If iteration is 18, output is 0
If iteration is 35, output is 1
If iteration is 86, output is 2

Comment: `iteration % range`

Comment: `If iteration is 35, output is 1` ???  are you sure ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan, I think so because it would be in the mid range 30-60, or there abouts.

Comment: Then it is smt like iteratoin/(limit/range)

Comment: @t.m. yes that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var limit = 90;   //Can change
var range = 3;    //1,2,3 - Can change
var iteration = 0;

function {
   var output = parseInt(iteration/(limit/range));

   console.log(output);
   iteration++;
}
```

Answered in the comments by t.m.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the fraction and multiply it with the wanted range.

```js
const getPart = (limit, range) => value => Math.floor(range * value/ limit);

var getRange = getPart(90, 3);

console.log(getRange(18)); // 0
console.log(getRange(35)); // 1
console.log(getRange(86)); // 2
```